# Comparing data in SQL Server and insert in another table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 3 tables in `SQL Server`. 2 of them consist text values and the third one is a junction table.

I need to compare the values of the first one with the second one to see which values of the first one are not in the second one.

Then I have to insert the `ID`s of these differences in the junction table, and also find the `ID`s of existing ones (which exist in both tables) from the junction table and add them again in the junction table.

How should I do that? Should I use iterator? How is it?

**EDIT**

My first table consists one column named `Text`.

My second table consists two columns named `ID` and `Text`.

My junction table consists three columns named `ID`, `Post_ID` and `Text_ID`

I need to compare `Text`s, insert the differences in second table. Then in junction table I have to insert `Text_ID`s of all first table's rows from second table with another `Post_ID`.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to your question showing how the tables look now, and how you expect them to be afterwards please?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do on the second half?
Finding the existing ones and add them again?

Comment: Now I'm confused :-(  
* insert the differences in second table  = insert the Text values from the first table that don't exist in the second?  
* insert Text_IDs of all first table's rows from second table with another Post_ID --> Please clarify, if from first table - it doesn't have any ID field.

Comment: Yes, differences means that. you got it :) Post_ID is something different that I get it from Scope_Identity(). That's not important! The problem is I just wanna insert the Text_IDs of differences and existings in junction table but for differences I have to insert them in second table too.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, use `INSERT` with `LEFT JOIN`.
Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 
SELECT TABLE1.ID
FROM   TABLE1 
       LEFT JOIN TABLE2 
              ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID 
WHERE  TABLE2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you feel about third party tools, but Toad for sql server (made by dell) has a tool specifically for this.

http://software.dell.com/landing/218/?gclid=CjwKEAjwyqOwBRDZuIO4p5SV8w0SJAAQoUSwC6B8BfgAQLML_8o3j9Bw1sUL01EljAjF9eXlZrY-nxoCYsjw_wcB